# How can I share object between threads in Perl?

Tags: perl, multithreading

I have searched for related topic, but still can't solve the problem...

```
use threads;
my $person = new Person( 'Name' => "yy");

my $udp_thread = threads->new(\&udp_func);

while(1)
{
    $person->working();
}

sub udp_func 
{
    #Can't call method "setName" on an undefined value:
    $person->setName();             
}
```

How can I visit the object $person in the new thread ? Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) Perl extension ?

> threads::shared - Perl extension for sharing data structures between threads. By default, variables are private to each thread, and each newly created thread gets a private copy of each existing variable. This module allows you to share variables across different threads (and pseudo-forks on Win32). It is used together with the threads module. This module supports the sharing of the following data types only: scalars and scalar refs, arrays and array refs, and hashes and hash refs.

Comment: Thanks for your help:) However, can threads::shared make a object(which is dynamically changed) shared between thread ?